# Issue with GRANT SELECT permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, user-permissions

I have a SQL view `[schemaA].[ViewNameA]` which is built on other views with different schemas:

- `[schemaB].[ViewNameB]`
- `[schemaC].[ViewNameC]`
- `[schemaD].[ViewNameD]`

I'm trying to provide access to `[schemaA].[ViewNameA]` for functional account "USERXYZ" with:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON [schemaA].[ViewNameA] to USERXYZ
```

When I log in with this "USERXYZ" account and try to run a select on `[schemaA].[ViewNameA]` I get an error like:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ViewNameB', database 'db1', schema 'schemaB'.

This account "USERXYZ" has role "public" on db1. How can I provide access to `[schemaA].[ViewNameA]` without granting select to `[schemaB].[ViewNameB]` and others?

I tried to manage schema permissions - `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` - but then the user had permissions to all views under schemaB.

Comment: Is `[schemaA].[ViewNameA]` also in the database `db1`? If they are, are the 2 objects *owned* by the same `USER` in `db1`?

Comment: Yes, schemaA is also in the same DB.SchemaA is owned by USER and SchemaB is owned by db owner.

Comment: Then permission chaining won't work; the `USER` will need explicit permissions on the object(s) or you'll need to use a different solution, such as signed objects.

Comment: So there is no chance that the user wont see the views and tables assigned to schema schemaB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask there.

Comment: Sorry. I understand that I need to give the user access to the schemaB object in order for the user to use the view with schema schemaA. In that case, the user will also have access to all objects under schema schemaB, which I would very much like to avoid

Comment: Why do you think giving the user access to a single object would give them access to *many* objects?

Comment: I used ALTER AUTHENTICATION command to provide access to schemaB to USER. Then I logged in to this account and I could see all views and tables from schemaB

Comment: Why? Why not `GRANT` the `USER` to `SELECT` on the object? Why give someone the keys to the house, when they only need to unlock the external storage box?

Comment: So just to sum up - I should GRANT SELECT on SchemaB to USER?

Comment: To the ***object*** *not* the *schema*.

Answer (score 0):

The error is *literally* telling you the problem here. The `USER` doesn't have permission to `SELECT` from the other object. From the comments you state that the objects are in the same database, but are owned by different `USER`s, so permission chaining won't work. As such why not just `GRANT` the `USER` the permission to `SELECT` from that object too? The syntax you already know, as you demonstrate it, but to confirm:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON [schemaB].[ViewNameB] to USERXYZ;
```

<sub>On a related note, however, you should *not* nest views; this can (will) have performance issues. Instead you should be referencing the objects you need to reference in `ViewNameA`, *not* referencing `ViewNameB`. A read of [Is nested view a good database design?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design) might be worthwhile.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help with it. I have one last doubt - USER will then have access to all the data from the [schemaB].[viewNameB], while on [schemaA].[viewNameA] he has only a portion of the columns from the source view

Comment: *Huh*? The above `GRANT` is no different to the one you have in your question; it will allow the `USER` to `SELECT` against the object; it doesn't `DENY` the using a `SELECT` against any specific columns. That *includes* your `GRANT`; they can get data from **all** the columns in `ViewNameA`. I'm starting to feel like the question you've asked, and the question you *need* to ask aren't the same thing.

Comment: Arguably granting `SELECT` on tables you don't need is a security problem in itself. Better to make both views and tables owned by `dbo` so chaining works, then grant access to the view that `UserA` needs. Also nested views are not in and of themselves problematic, it's that they commonly contain constructs that cannot be easily optimized away, such as aggregation or window functions, or unnecessary joins.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface! It is the solution that i was looking for! Now the USER can select from the ViewNameA without possibility to SELECT ViewNameB.

Comment: I, in truth, assumed that the objects had different owners for a reason, @Charlieface, and so why I didn't suggest it. Of course, if there *isn't* a good reason then I agree that having the same owner would be the better option.